# jasmine angularjs testing - Argument 'PhoneListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

When running an angularjs + Jasmine + Karma test, I got following error:
[image]

My test script is:

```
describe('PhoneCat controllers', function() {

  describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){

    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function($controller) {
      var scope = {},
          ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', { $scope: scope });

      expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
    }));
  });
});
```

This code is just a copy from official AngularJS tutorial here:
http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/tutorial/step_02

Here is part of my karma.conf.js file:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [

    'js/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'js/bower_components/angular/ngular-mocks.js',
    'js/app/controllers.js',
    'test/unit/*.js'
],
```

The error is **PhoneListCtrl** not define, but I beleive it is defined and loaded in the above code. What do you think is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like my unit test file is not aware of the the controller PhoneListCtrl. How should I build the dependency? If anybody can recommend a good tutorials for angular + Jasmine + karma testing tutorials?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Module initialization part is missing in your unit test. You should call `module('phonecatApp')` before you first time call `inject()`. Your unit test code in this case should look like:

```
describe('PhoneCat controllers', function() {

  describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){

    beforeEach(function() {
      module('phonecatApp'); // <= initialize module that should be tested
    });

    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function($controller) {
      var scope = {},
          ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', { $scope: scope });

      expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
    }));
  });
});
```

where `phonecatApp` is the name of the module where you defined your `PhoneListCtrl` controller.

Also tutorial you are using is outdated, it is for unstable version of Angular (1.2.0-rc.3). Here is an updated version of the same tutorial for the latest version of Angular: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02

Comment: Gosh... Thank you so much,Vadim! I would never figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
describe('addCatControllerTest', function() {

    describe('addCatController', function(){

        beforeEach(function() {
            module('app');
        });

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        }));

        it('Add Cat Controller test', inject(function($controller) {
            var scope = {},
                ctrl = $controller('addCatController', { $scope: scope });
            expect(scope.title).toBe('Add Cat');
        }));
    });
});
```