# $controller service throwing error while loading controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm using Angular 1.5.8. Here is my code:

```
describe('My Controller', function() {
    var MyController;
    var $controller;
    var $rootScope;
    var $state;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ui.router'));
    beforeEach(module('app.my.ctrl'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$state_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $state = _$state_;
        MyController = $controller('MyController', { scope: $rootScope.$new() });
    }));

    describe('#init', function() {
        it('should do something', function() {
            console.log('logStatement', MyController);

            MyController.init();

            expect(true).toBe(true);
        })

    })
});
```

The test runner is able to locate all files, so this isnt a case of forgetting to load something. When I run this test, not only does the `logStatement` never appear, I get this error:

```
Argument 'MyController' is not a function, got undefined
```

This is my controller:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.my.ctrl')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = [
    '$scope'
];
/* ngInject */
function MyController($scope) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.hello = 'world';

    vm.init = function() {
        return true;
    }
}

})();
```

and this is my karma conf file:

```
// Karma configuration

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'src/controllers/MyController.js',
      'tests/unit/**/*.spec.js',
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      '**/*.swp'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['spec'],

    //  Spec Reporter Config
    specReporter: {
    //     suppressErrorSummary: false,
    //     suppressFailed: false,
    //     suppressPassed: false,
        suppressSkipped: true
    //     showSpecTiming: false
    },


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

What does this mean?? I can't find anything in the documentation that would explain this.

**UPDATE:**

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045706/jasmine-angularjs-testing-argument-phonelistctrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefined) and the answer has not worked.

Comment: What is the name of the module that your controller is defined under?

Comment: Please read the snippet. `'app.my.ctrl'`

Comment: I read that, was  just making sure that was right.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: post your `karma.conf.js` and the definition of your controller. Are you adding the `angular-mocks` library?

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia yes. see updated question.

Comment: Where is your `app.my.ctrl` module **defined**? My guess is, you aren't including that file in your Karma `files` list

Comment: it is defined otherwise an error would have been thrown at the `module('app.my.ctrl)` line.

Comment: I think you need to add that module definition file to the karma files array, try doing it

Answer (score 3):

Trying change the service injected in the controller from `scope` to `$scope`

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$state_) {
      $controller = _$controller_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $state = _$state_;
      MyController = $controller('MyController', { $scope: $rootScope.$new()});
}));
```

Comment: This is certainly the *next problem* OP will run into but not the current one :)

Comment: Please only add answers that have been tested.

Comment: Using your code works for me except by this answer. I recommend to you that check if you controller .js file has been loaded in the karma process. For this open your browser in the url **http://localhost:9876/debug.html" using the `karma start --no-single-run` command. Try by example print after the line 'use strict' in your controller a console.log or check if the controller has been loaded in the `Sources` tab in the Chrome develop tools.

Comment: @dopatraman, this answer may not contain the entire answer, but for sure, Gonzalo is right, you don't inject the scope using the correct property name. Therefore dependency injector cannot possibly match your "scope" property to the "$scope" controller parameter. This will end with a failure of the creation of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to make your pb as simple as possible? Inside the application can you successfully make this call? `$controller('MyController', { $scope: $rootScope.$new()});` . If this works (it actually should), the problem definitively comes from your test/jasmin/karma/gulp/grunt configuration and you shouldn't dig into angular direction anymore. Can you give us a look at how you define the `app.my.ctrl` module in your application? Maybe this module depends on more modules than only `ui.router` that you mock in your test. If it's the case, the module can't be loaded, and any controller inside can't be created either.

Comment: "no dice"... I don't understand. Does that mean that the simple call out of the test context doesn't work? or does it mean that your module doesn't contain more dependencies. (for information the module definition is the only important thing you didn't mention in your post)

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('My Controller', function() {
  var MyController;
  var scope;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ui.router'));
  beforeEach(module('app.my.ctrl'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  describe('#init', function() {
      it('should do something', function($componentController) {
          var MyController = $componentController('MyController', {
                $scope : scope
            });
          MyController.init();

          expect(true).toBe(true);
      })

  })
});
```